# Are the уж (a kind of snake) and узко (narrow) related?

Tags: этимология

According to Mallory we have the following PIE words (in this notation, g = palatal/plain ġ=plain/uvular):

***a̯enġhu̯is*** snake (> уж)

***a̯enghus*** narrow (> узко)

***a̯enghnos*** fear, constriction (> ужас)

This hints at that the words could be related if the exact value of the g was determined wrongly.

I also wonder whether the following words are related:

***e̯oġhu̯is*** snake, serpent (in Fortson, ***e̯eghu̯is***). Mallory claims this is unrelated to the ***a̯enġhu̯is***. Fortson claims it is related to the following entry and reconstructs the same consonant in the root. Mallory claims that the "traditional school" derived hedgehog as "snake-eater". The Brill etymological dictionary of Latin reconstructs the initial a̯- here and links this root to the ***a̯enġhu̯is***, claiming that the -n- infix appeared here due to analogy.

***e̯eghis*** hedgehog (> russ. ёж, eng. hedgehog)

***e̯eghs*** out

***e̯egherom*** lake (> russ. озеро)

If ***e̯oġhu̯is***, it could be connected to ***e̯eġhu̯ti*** drinks

Comment: This question is, actually, about PIE, and even not about the Slavic languages in general. In the Slavic languages the 2 words are not related.

Comment: So what? The question is, actually, about etymology of two modern Russian words. Ulike posting Modern Russian endings onto Proto-Slavic words, it's fine.

Comment: @Manjusri But the question is off topic here. This site is for Russian, the current modern language. Questions like this are better for the [linguistics.se] site.

Comment: Migrated [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3266/111).

Comment: @Alenanno Right, let's delete each and every question with tags pertaining to language history then. I doubt the question being off-topic here. It's about the history of Russian language.

Comment: @Manjusri No need to do that, but questions like this are better off in the other site.

Comment: @Alenanno The other site has a lot of 'wise' guys willing to judge any question out of their too narrow scope as 'not a real question'. Arrogance is international disaster # 1.